# light-locker expose my playing sound when switch tty by keyboard?

Tags: debian, permissions, pulseaudio, lxde, light-locker

How to solved or bypass this problem?

light-locker can hide my screen but very short time expose my screen contents when first switch to my screen by keyboard.

sound contents is always expose nearl like "normal" play.

```
$light-locker --version
light-locker 1.7.0
$pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 10.0
#pulseaudio is run as non-root user
$sudo pgrep --uid 0 pulseaudio 
$sudo pgrep --euid 0 pulseaudio 
$cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
$
```

Answer (score 0):

For sound expose:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1364597

For very short time screen contents expose:
maybe bind some window manager shortcut key to some action can helpful to the "short expose" problem.